# Getting very different results for statistics timing in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to time/benchmark a query as part of a bigger performance analysis.

In SQL, I have enabled timing via `SET statistics time ON` and the query I am timing looks like `SELECT A, B from foo where id = 123`. Before each query, I execute:

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

Below are the results of 2 runs (not subsequently):

**Run 1:**

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 8 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

(1212 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 15 ms.
```

**Run 2:**

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 3 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

(1212 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 16 ms,  elapsed time = 14 ms.
```

What I don't understand is:

1. Why are there 2 'parse and compile time' sections and why are the results different within the same query?
2. Are the parse and compile time included in the CPU time below them
3. Why is the CPU time 0 in 'run 1'
4. Why is the CPU time more than the elapsed time in 'run 2'

It is not very clear what number provides the CPU **User** time, that is how long did my query actually take which should be at most the elapsed time.

On the bigger picture, I have a data intensive application that reads only from the database - each query is fast but it can query for a lot of data and it does this via individual queries, not in bulk. Is it a problem that I am trying to time an individual query - should I construct an sql script which takes a more meaningful time than a few milliseconds? To me the answer is 'Yes' but I am worried about not understanding the behaviour on a microscopic test before moving to a macroscopic test.

Comment: `it does this via individual queries, not in bulk` - that is the issue, not millisecond differences within statistical error range. Are you running tests on desktop/laptop or any other away from production environment? Are you running tests on shared hardware?

Comment: Use "Client Statistics", and run your query over 10 times to get a better result set. You can compare Run 1 and Run 2.

Comment: @IvanStarostin it is, but I am trying to evaluate the performance on filtering on primary key and an index. I've simplified the query to a simple select statement and I'd like to understand how the 2 versions will compare because a bulk query will inherit a lot of the performance characteristics, just scaled

Comment: Side note, you need to run `CHECKPOINT` before `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS`. But I personally wouldn't bother with [`DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` for performance testing](http://www.dbdelta.com/performance-testing-with-dbcc-dropcleanbuffers/)

Comment: @mvisser Looking into - thanks!

Comment: Are you executing from remote server or local? If remote then execute same query on server by cmd.

Comment: @mvisser OK, so resetting the Client Statistics and executing the query > 10 times consecutively, would the "Total execution time" give me accurate results of roughly how long the query takes?

Comment: Yes and No. It depends from where you running your quey from. Using c# .NET they have there own execution plan. SSIS/SSRS then yes this will be more accurate.

Comment: @mvisser I am actually running it from within SQL Server Studio. I have also written some python to execute 100,000 queries with a different id and hopefully this will give me a good relative performance metric.

Comment: But even though Management Studio will sometimes have a different execution plan than running the same query through Python. All you can do is build your indexes based on the query. Or create a Stored Procedure and just execute the SP.